# Passing from manual Docker host network to Docker Compose bridge

Tags: docker, docker-compose, pymodbus3

I have 2 docker images a modbus server and a client which I run manually with `docker run --network host server` and the same with the client and work perfectly. But now I need to add them to a docker-compose file where the network is bridge, what I did like this:

```
autoserver:
    image: 19mikel95/pymodmikel:autoserversynchub
    container_name: autoserver
    restart: unless-stopped

  clientperf:
    image: 19mikel95/pymodmikel:reloadcomp
    container_name: clientperf
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - autoserver
    links:
      - "autoserver:server"
```

And I read that to refer from a container  to another one(client to server) I have to use the service name in the dockercompose YML (autoserver) so that is what I did. In the python file executed in the client(which is the [performance.py](https://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/example/performance.html) from pymodbus) I changed 'localhost' to:

```
host = 'autoserver'
client = ModbusTcpClient(host, port=5020)
```

However I get this error:

> [ERROR/MainProcess] failed to run test successfully Traceback (most
> recent call last):   File "performance.py", line 72, in
> single_client_test
> client.read_holding_registers(10, 1, unit=1)
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pymodbus/client/common.py", line
> 114, in read_holding_registers
> return self.execute(request)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pymodbus/client/sync.py", line 107, in
> execute
> raise ConnectionException("Failed to connect[%s]" % (self.**str**())) pymodbus.exceptions.ConnectionException: Modbus
> Error: [Connection] Failed to
> connect[ModbusTcpClient(autoserver:5020)]

as asked, my full docker-compose YML is this:

```
version: '2.1'

networks:
  monitor-net:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
    prometheus_data: {}
    grafana_data: {}

services:

  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:latest
    container_name: prometheus
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus:/etc/prometheus
      - prometheus_data:/prometheus
    command:
      - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
      - '--storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus'
      - '--web.console.libraries=/etc/prometheus/console_libraries'
      - '--web.console.templates=/etc/prometheus/consoles'
      - '--storage.tsdb.retention.time=200h'
      - '--web.enable-lifecycle'
    restart: unless-stopped
    expose:
      - 9090
    networks:
      - monitor-net
    labels:
      org.label-schema.group: "monitoring"

  alertmanager:
    image: prom/alertmanager:latest
    container_name: alertmanager
    volumes:
      - ./alertmanager:/etc/alertmanager
    command:
      - '--config.file=/etc/alertmanager/config.yml'
      - '--storage.path=/alertmanager'
    restart: unless-stopped
    expose:
      - 9093
    networks:
      - monitor-net
    labels:
      org.label-schema.group: "monitoring"

  nodeexporter:
    image: prom/node-exporter:latest
    container_name: nodeexporter
    volumes:
      - /proc:/host/proc:ro
      - /sys:/host/sys:ro
      - c:\:/rootfs:ro
    command:
      - '--path.procfs=/host/proc'
      - '--path.rootfs=/rootfs'
      - '--path.sysfs=/host/sys'
      - '--collector.filesystem.ignored-mount-points=^/(sys|proc|dev|host|etc)($$|/)'
    restart: unless-stopped
    expose:
      - 9100
    networks:
      - monitor-net
    labels:
      org.label-schema.group: "monitoring"

  cadvisor:
    image: gcr.io/google-containers/cadvisor:latest
    container_name: cadvisor
    volumes:
      - c:\:/rootfs:ro
      - /var/run:/var/run:rw
      - /sys:/sys:ro
      - /var/lib/docker:/var/lib/docker:ro
      #- /cgroup:/cgroup:ro #doesn't work on MacOS only for Linux
    restart: unless-stopped
    expose:
      - 8080
    networks:
      - monitor-net
    labels:
      org.label-schema.group: "monitoring"

  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana:latest
    container_name: grafana
    volumes:
      - grafana_data:/var/lib/grafana
      - ./grafana/provisioning:/etc/grafana/provisioning
    environment:
      - GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_USER=${ADMIN_USER:-admin}
      - GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD=${ADMIN_PASSWORD:-admin}
      - GF_USERS_ALLOW_SIGN_UP=false
    restart: unless-stopped
    expose:
      - 3000
    networks:
      - monitor-net
    labels:
      org.label-schema.group: "monitoring"

  pushgateway:
    image: prom/pushgateway:latest
    container_name: pushgateway
    restart: unless-stopped
    expose:
      - 9091
    networks:
      - monitor-net
    labels:
      org.label-schema.group: "monitoring"

  caddy:
    image: stefanprodan/caddy
    container_name: caddy
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      - "9090:9090"
      - "9093:9093"
      - "9091:9091"
    volumes:
      - ./caddy:/etc/caddy
    environment:
      - ADMIN_USER=${ADMIN_USER:-admin}
      - ADMIN_PASSWORD=${ADMIN_PASSWORD:-admin}
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - monitor-net
    labels:
      org.label-schema.group: "monitoring"

  autoserver:
    image: 19mikel95/pymodmikel:autoserversynchub
    container_name: autoserver
    ports:
      - "5020:5020"
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - monitor-net

  clientperf:
    image: 19mikel95/pymodmikel:reloadcomp
    container_name: clientperf
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - monitor-net
    depends_on:
      - autoserver
    links:
      - "autoserver:server"
```

Comment: Have you verified that the `autoserver` container is running and ready to accept connections?

Comment: yes, it is perfectly running

Comment: @19mike95 could you please share the whole `docker-compose.yaml` file?

Comment: Did you try creating an env variable for  host and give that as the host on your code?

Comment: @DmytroSerdiuk done, although I have done some changes and it might be not be exactly the same of the part I posted the first time

Comment: @Subbu what would that change?

Comment: @19mike95  I see `host= 'autoserver'` on the code that you provided. Here python considering 'autoserver' as string

Comment: @Subbu yes, however i think that is how its supposed to work, because if llok into the performance.py file from pymodbus they use host = '127.0.0.1' to specify localhost.

Comment: I think you don't need the `links` in `clientperf`. When using the same networks, it can be accessible via host name already.

Comment: @ThinhTran yes i know it is not needed, however as it was not working I tried just in case

Comment: @19mike95 It's strange. Have you tried to run some dns troubleshooting commands like `nslookup autoserver` or `dig autoserver` on your client container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `StartTcpServer(context, identity=identity, address=("localhost", 5020))` of `sincserver.py` file from `autoserver` image. The `localhost` allows for TcpServer to accept connection only from `localhost`. It should be replaced with `0.0.0.0` in order to allow any external requests to this port.

The following Docker Compose shows it (`sed -i 's|localhost|0.0.0.0|g' sincserver.py` replaces the hostname):

```yaml
version: '2.1'

services:
  autoserver:
    image: 19mikel95/pymodmikel:autoserversynchub
    command: sh -c "
      sed -i 's|localhost|0.0.0.0|g' sincserver.py;
      python3 sincserver.py daemon off
      "
    ports:
      - "5020:5020"
    restart: unless-stopped

  clientperf:
    image: 19mikel95/pymodmikel:reloadcomp
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - autoserver
```

Run:

```sh
docker-compose up -d
docker-compose logs -f clientperf
```

And you will see log like

```
clientperf_1  | [DEBUG/MainProcess] 574 requests/second
clientperf_1  | [DEBUG/MainProcess] time taken to complete 1000 cycle by 10 workers is 1.7410697999875993 seconds
clientperf_1  | [DEBUG/MainProcess] 692 requests/second
clientperf_1  | [DEBUG/MainProcess] time taken to complete 1000 cycle by 10 workers is 1.4434449000109453 seconds
clientperf_1  | [DEBUG/MainProcess] 708 requests/second
clientperf_1  | [DEBUG/MainProcess] time taken to complete 1000 cycle by 10 workers is 1.4116760999895632 seconds
clientperf_1  | [DEBUG/MainProcess] 890 requests/second
clientperf_1  | [DEBUG/MainProcess] time taken to complete 1000 cycle by 10 workers is 1.1230684999900404 seconds
clientperf_1  | [DEBUG/MainProcess] 803 requests/second
clientperf_1  | [DEBUG/MainProcess] time taken to complete 1000 cycle by 10 workers is 1.2450218999874778 seconds
clientperf_1  | [DEBUG/MainProcess] 753 requests/second
clientperf_1  | [DEBUG/MainProcess] time taken to complete 1000 cycle by 10 workers is 1.3274328999978025 seconds
clientperf_1  | [DEBUG/MainProcess] 609 requests/second
clientperf_1  | [DEBUG/MainProcess] time taken to complete 1000 cycle by 10 workers is 1.6399398999928962 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the env variable like AUTO_SERVER_HOST and call this in your code

```
version: '2.1'

networks:
  monitor-net:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
    prometheus_data: {}
    grafana_data: {}

services:

  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:latest
    container_name: prometheus
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus:/etc/prometheus
      - prometheus_data:/prometheus
    command:
      - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
      - '--storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus'
      - '--web.console.libraries=/etc/prometheus/console_libraries'
      - '--web.console.templates=/etc/prometheus/consoles'
      - '--storage.tsdb.retention.time=200h'
      - '--web.enable-lifecycle'
    restart: unless-stopped
    expose:
      - 9090
    networks:
      - monitor-net
    labels:
      org.label-schema.group: "monitoring"

  alertmanager:
    image: prom/alertmanager:latest
    container_name: alertmanager
    volumes:
      - ./alertmanager:/etc/alertmanager
    command:
      - '--config.file=/etc/alertmanager/config.yml'
      - '--storage.path=/alertmanager'
    restart: unless-stopped
    expose:
      - 9093
    networks:
      - monitor-net
    labels:
      org.label-schema.group: "monitoring"

  nodeexporter:
    image: prom/node-exporter:latest
    container_name: nodeexporter
    volumes:
      - /proc:/host/proc:ro
      - /sys:/host/sys:ro
      - c:\:/rootfs:ro
    command:
      - '--path.procfs=/host/proc'
      - '--path.rootfs=/rootfs'
      - '--path.sysfs=/host/sys'
      - '--collector.filesystem.ignored-mount-points=^/(sys|proc|dev|host|etc)($$|/)'
    restart: unless-stopped
    expose:
      - 9100
    networks:
      - monitor-net
    labels:
      org.label-schema.group: "monitoring"

  cadvisor:
    image: gcr.io/google-containers/cadvisor:latest
    container_name: cadvisor
    volumes:
      - c:\:/rootfs:ro
      - /var/run:/var/run:rw
      - /sys:/sys:ro
      - /var/lib/docker:/var/lib/docker:ro
      #- /cgroup:/cgroup:ro #doesn't work on MacOS only for Linux
    restart: unless-stopped
    expose:
      - 8080
    networks:
      - monitor-net
    labels:
      org.label-schema.group: "monitoring"

  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana:latest
    container_name: grafana
    volumes:
      - grafana_data:/var/lib/grafana
      - ./grafana/provisioning:/etc/grafana/provisioning
    environment:
      - GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_USER=${ADMIN_USER:-admin}
      - GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD=${ADMIN_PASSWORD:-admin}
      - GF_USERS_ALLOW_SIGN_UP=false
    restart: unless-stopped
    expose:
      - 3000
    networks:
      - monitor-net
    labels:
      org.label-schema.group: "monitoring"

  pushgateway:
    image: prom/pushgateway:latest
    container_name: pushgateway
    restart: unless-stopped
    expose:
      - 9091
    networks:
      - monitor-net
    labels:
      org.label-schema.group: "monitoring"

  caddy:
    image: stefanprodan/caddy
    container_name: caddy
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      - "9090:9090"
      - "9093:9093"
      - "9091:9091"
    volumes:
      - ./caddy:/etc/caddy
    environment:
      - ADMIN_USER=${ADMIN_USER:-admin}
      - ADMIN_PASSWORD=${ADMIN_PASSWORD:-admin}
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - monitor-net
    labels:
      org.label-schema.group: "monitoring"

  autoserver:
    image: 19mikel95/pymodmikel:autoserversynchub
    container_name: autoserver
    ports:
      - "5020:5020"
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - monitor-net

  clientperf:
    image: 19mikel95/pymodmikel:reloadcomp
    container_name: clientperf
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - monitor-net
    depends_on:
      - autoserver
    environment:
      - AUTO_SERVER_HOST=autoserver
```

Call env variable like below

```
host = os.environ['AUTO_SERVER_HOST']
client = ModbusTcpClient(host, port=5020)
```

Comment: `ERROR: The Compose file '.\docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for services.clientperf: 'env' `   and also tried with 'enviroment' which is the one supposed to work in docker-compose 2.1 but still got the same error.

Comment: is there any specific reason for using the docker-compose version: '2.1'?

Comment: I am using drockprom and there is no newer version for docker-compose 3

Comment: managed to use the environment still got the same error as alwways `File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pymodbus/client/sync.py", line 107, in execute
    raise ConnectionException("Failed to connect[%s]" % (self.__str__()))
pymodbus.exceptions.ConnectionException: Modbus Error: [Connection] Failed to connect[ModbusTcpClient(autoserver:5020)]`

Comment: Let's debug it. can you print `os.environ['AUTO_SERVER_HOST']` and see what it is giving?

Comment: It is not needed it's returning 'autoserver' it can be seen in the error above ModbusTcpClient(**autoserver**:5020)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217788/discussion-between-19mike95-and-subbu).